# Map enum entries to specific types and values

Tags: typescript

**EDIT in response to comments:**

```
// FYI: localforage is can be basically treated as localStorage

enum LocalDbKeys {
  Mode = 'mode',           // localforage.getItem('mode') type is 0 | 1
  Countdown = 'countdown', // localforage.getItem('countdown') type is number
  Text = 'text',           // localforage.getItem('text') type is string
}

function watch<Type>(key: LocalDbKeys): Type {
  return localforage.getItem(key);
}

const result = watch<0 | 1>(LocalDbKeys.Mode);
if (result === 'some string') { // compiler will catch this error: "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap"

}

const result2 = watch<string>(LocalDbKeys.Mode); // however I can still make a mistake with the type, so this bug slips through:
if (result2 === 'some string') {                 // I want to include the type information of what's in localforage.getItem(key), so the compiler catches my mistake

}

// BELOW IS CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK
// but is an example  of what I really want; some way to declare the watch function like this to eliminate all errors:

const newWay1 = watch<LocalDbKeys.Mode>();      // at this point the compiler knows that newWay1 is type 0 | 1
const newWay2 = watch<LocalDbKeys.Countdown>(); // at this point the compiler knows that newWay2 is type number
const newWay3 = watch<LocalDbKeys.Text>();      // at this point the compiler knows that newWay3 is type string

// or alternatively without generics, just by parameter:
const alternative = watch(LocalDbKeys.Mode); // etc
```

**Original:**

I have a bunch of keys which access data in localstorage of several different types. This is my current working code:

```
enum LocalDbKeys {
  Mode = 'mode',
  Countdown = 'countdown',
}
```

```
watch<Type>(key: LocalDbKeys): any { ... }
```

```
const result = watch<0 | 1>(LocalDbKeys.Mode);
```

However I don't want to be able to make the mistake of getting the typing incorrect in multiple places. E.g. accidentally doing this:

```
const result = watch<0 | 1>(LocalDbKeys.Mode); // place one
//...
const result = watch<string>(LocalDbKeys.Mode); // place two, erroneous
```

What I really want to be able to do, is have a map of types for each LocalDbKey, so the compiler will immediately know if I've made a type error. For example:

```
const result = watch<LocalDbKeys.Mode>();
if (result === 'a string') // this would be caught immediately, because it can only be 0 | 1
```

I imagine this would be done with some kind of map of entries to types?

Comment: Why does `watch` need to be generic? In your examples it's not needed.

Comment: What exactly would your expected result be? Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies the problem?

Comment: I've editted my original comment to include a more complete example at the bottom, hopefully answering both of these questions.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLqGAW) meet your needs?  I don't think you really need an `enum` here, since [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w1PYGW) works just fine, but it's up to you whether you want an extra layer of indirection between the column names and your TS code.  Anyway if this works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks jcalz - I agree I'll get rid of the enum all together. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  Note that I didn't get alerted to your response; if you want to be sure to notify someone, you should @-mention them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do indeed need to express the mapping from `key` to the desired output type of `watch(key)`.  This can be accomplished with [an `interface` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces):

```
interface DbProps {
    [LocalDbKeys.Mode]: 0 | 1,
    [LocalDbKeys.Countdown]: number,
    [LocalDbKeys.Text]: string
}
```

Then `watch()` can be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `key`, and the output type can be the corresponding [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `DbProps[K]`:

```
function watch<K extends LocalDbKeys>(key: K): DbProps[K] {
    return localStorage.getItem(key) as any;
}

const mode = watch(LocalDbKeys.Mode); // 0 | 1
const cdwn = watch(LocalDbKeys.Countdown); // number
const text = watch(LocalDbKeys.Text); // string
```

Depending on your needs you could dispense with the enum entirely:

```
interface DbProps {
    mode: 0 | 1,
    countdown: number,
    text: string
}

const mode = watch("mode"); // 0 | 1
const cdwn = watch("countdown"); // number
const text = watch("text"); // string
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AlgFwBYFFgFcwkBvAKFKUqQgKIBkB7eEAGwBEAjAaQgE8oSFKsICyDACbIAvEgDkYCRFkAaYWsoB6DUhZNWAMwYAnEAHMIAOnMYAkhghgAFPMWyAlEgy8YyNAIAMSAA+SACMQuoAwgz4wBjiDADuwEgysvAxcQnJKkhaOnoshibmVhC29k7pmfFJwO6e3r4CtBwQRhFqACoQAB4YqXL2-bnqwvm6zEXGZpbWdg7OwxgNXj5IfkhQGEZowKadAL7kwnv2RvoIyJwACkYMMAJkY0gA2oxTnDz8FmKSALoALiQgRCoWUnWE70KXz4UAs0VitWSQKQrXaEJe0M+3DhFh6-VR212+yOJyo+li8AwaAYKUSIAw8CwAB4uNR+jRxAIPqxYfwAHyOADWfGBXDcwNu90ery4-0ELyM5XwRhSk1YAGUMDNSvNKiK+B4QAIQMBeABuMmdDLAbZIBSSQYMplYRy89i4n5-CBuC15bSgsKdfJUAB6AH4bXT7fBxMlnYzme6YV74YisnU-QG0YQ2h1xtpw1HhLb7ctE66UzjvvCCRhs-liXsDoXhJHyMdSKBILArqhMFgYhg8IRBOTKGd2pdEEhpQ8npCqI6IMCg+Cl5QMkjssBgeijJixstgc3ScIu8JKcBqbT6UnWey+vZgNykKLeAx9HOOHcF0KP3FSUfz-WV5UVMZlQwVV1UKbVdTmcoFicD9jVNc0rQvCckDLAYV0rZMACIV0IxtA2CYM22LaM7QGOMExkF0iO3TNklI-18gPEMi0oDtSxjAYK0Yh9HEI5Z2JzM9WyoUNeKjUhDiAA)